# Change numbers with regex in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, replace

I'm trying to put in `5` between every `1value`+`px` so `1px` should become `15px` and `100px` should become `1005px`.

I'm searching with `1(.*?)px` and replacing with `1$15px` but that's not working...

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since this was asked, but for anyone else who encounters a similar problem, here's a simple answer that works.

In Sublime Text 2, the following replace string will give you the result you're asking for.

```
1${1}5px
```

Example text:

```
1px 
100px 1px and 100px

1px 100px 1px and 100px 1px 
100px 1px and 100px1px 
100px 1px and 100px
```

Find What:

```
1(.*?)px
```

Replace With:

```
1${1}5px
```

Result:

```
15px 
1005px 15px and 1005px

15px 1005px 15px and 1005px 15px 
1005px 15px and 1005px15px 
1005px 15px and 1005px
```

This uses the *named* group substitution `${ name }` instead of the *number* group substitution `$ number`. In this case the number one stands for the name.

For some reason the Sublime Text 2 regex engine doesn't work well with substitution when numbers follow the numbered group.

Answer (score 0):

Your replacement probably looks like capture group `$15` rather than `$1`. I'm not familiar with sublimetext2 but you probably need to escape your replacement like this:

```
s/1(.*?)px/1${1}5px/
```

That would certainly be the correct syntax in perl which appears to be very similar syntax to that which you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 2 uses the backslash to refer to capture groups so `\1` instead of `$1`

Find What: `(1\d*) ?px`

Replace With: `\15px`

As there is no capture group 15 this will work fine.